# Phonegap Build 3.3.0- Impossible to connect to Facebook

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have been working 3 days (night and day) straight to try to connect a phonegap build app to Facebook. I have used all sorts of plug-ins such as

- Facebook connect (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)
- FaceGap (https://github.com/studiosoton/faceGap) and even
- openfb (can't post the link as I need a reputation of 10)

I have also tried the example pgb-fbconnect-master and I have added (and later removed) some relevant plugins in my config.xml file such as Inappbrowser and Childbrowser but to no avail at all :(.

The last version of my code even works on Chrome Ripple Emulator (facebook login pops up if user is not logged in and once the user is logged it it extracts the profile info and displays them in a DIV but this dream unfortunately comes to an end when I upload and build the phonegap app and test it on a real Ipad and Android device. 
Here is the javascript (myscript.js):

```
window.onload=function() { 
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
} else {
    onDeviceReady();
}
};

function onDeviceReady() { 
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
$.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
    alert("Loaded FB successfully!");

    FB.init({
  'appId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'xfbml'      : true,
  'cookie'  : true, 
  'oauth': true,
  'status':true
  });

   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        alert(response.status);
        getUserInfo();
    } else {
         $("#fb-root").show();
        FB.login(function(){},{scope: 'public_profile' //publish_actions}); 
      }
   });

   function getUserInfo() {
   FB.api("/me", function(data) {
     if (data.error) {
        alert('Unexpected Facebook Login Error: ' + JSON.stringify(data.error));
    } else {
        $('#account-info').html(// '<img src="' + data.url + '">' 
                                                  '<img src="' +    
           'http://graph.facebook.com/' + data.id + '/picture?type=small' + '">'
                                                + "<p>Name: "+data.name + "</p>"
                                                + "<p>Gender: "+data.gender+ "</p>"
                                                + "<p>FB page last modified on:"
                                                +data.updated_time+ "</p>"
                                    );
        }
       });
      }
```

Here is the config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id        = "com.phonegap.example"
version   = "1.0.0">
 <name>TestApp</name>
 <icon src="images/on.png" width="57" height="57" density="mdpi" />
 <description>
 A simple PhoneGap Build application.
</description>
<author href="https://my.com" email=",my@example.com">
Hansi
</author>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
<param name="APP_ID" value="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
<param name="APP_NAME" value="TestApp" />
</gap:plugin>
</widget>
```

And finally he is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Place searches</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js">    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1" class="ui-corner-all">
<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
<ul>
<li><a href="#page" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#favs" data-icon="star">Recently Requested</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-icon="gear">Setup</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<h1>Facebookish</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<!-- script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script -->

<h2>Profile</h2>
<div id="account-info"></div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<h4>Test App &copy;</h4>
</div>
</div>  
<!-- script src="scripts/openfb.js" type="text/javascript"></script -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<!--script src="phonegap.js"></script-->
<script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script> 
<script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have not included the files cordova.js, cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js, and facebook-js-sdk.js in the web directory because I have read that they will generated during the building process (although during testing in Netbeans I got errors for those missing files). I have also commented phonegap.js out because none of the examples on the Web used it.

What am I doing wrong? As mentioned previously, in theory it all works in Ripple emulator but after building it in Phonegap build, the app loses that Facebook connection behaviour. 
72 hours of toil for nothing :).

Your help will be appreciated.